# Downloading Android plaform source code

Tags: android, git, repository

Is it possible to download Android platform source code using GIT instead of REPO command as described in official developer documentation ?

Comment: you can use git clone command. btw Why you want to clone repos separately using git instead of repo??

Comment: Repo uses git commands internally. Use --trace with repo commands to check what commands are run by repo internally. e.g. "repo --trace branch . "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repo is just a wrapper of Git, so the answer is yes. However, you'd have to manually download the manifest git, parse the manifest to figure out which gits to fetch and where in the workspace to place them, and finally fetch them. So while possible, it's very unclear why one would want to do this if you really want a full Android source workspace.

Comment: some critical functionality changed during a week or so period, i would like to have the code from the point in time when i downloaded it for the first time

Comment: on this link [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest) i found following commnad _git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest_. This command should give me manifest in the way you suggest ?

Comment: Yes, `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest` is a fine way to clone the AOSP manifest git. But I don't see how this brings you any closer to being able to go back in time for the whole workspace. How to accomplish _that_ is what you should be asking.